# Reading only one row from mysql when there are two

Tags: php, mysql

I need the script to output both rows.  However, I can only get it to output the first one.  Help please!

Here is my code:

```
  <?php 
$server = ""; // assume server name 
$connect = mysqli_connect($server,,,) //assume password etc.
or die ("Couldn't connect to server"); //connect to admin database
$query = "SELECT mt FROM Content";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)
 or die ('Could not execute query.');
$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 30)
{
echo $row[$i];
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only fetch the first row.
You should do a while loop on your mysqli_fetch_array() to get both rows.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
        echo $row[$i];
    }
}
```

That should do it (like some of the other posted while I was writing but they forgot parts of the answer :-)

But I think that you should use the OO way of using mysqli.

Answer (score 5):

You need to fetch into a row in a loop:

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try to type:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{
    echo $row[$i];
    $i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to fetch all of the records.